# "Comment on their character" or "comment on their characters"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

> I would like to say a few words to comment on their character(**s**).

I am wondering if "character" in the sense of qualities of personality is a count noun and can be pluralized. Macmillan and Cambridge dictionaries are vague with reference to this. Macmillan says this specific usage is countable, while Cambridge suggests it is countable and uncountable.

When I talk about multiple people's different personalities should I use the plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   Use the plural to denote separate characters, individual characters.   The singular would indicate that the people involved share the same character -- a reasonable idea, but not the one that you intend to express.   Character as an aspect of personality is just as countable as those personalities themselves.

Comment: Well, yes and no.  "Character" is both countable and uncountable, depending on which particular definition you mean.  In this case it's hard to say which makes more sense without a lot more context.

Comment: OP provides "multiple people's different personalities" as the context.  Why would we need a lot more, @Andrew?

Comment: It depends on what you want to say.  Do you want to explain how they are all different, or how, despite their differences, they are similar?  In any case there's probably a more elegant way to phrase this.

Answer (score 1):

No. The word character as you want to use it cannot be pluralized. You would just say "comment on their character".

Comment: I don't think this is *entirely* true.  You can most certainly say "comment on their *characters*" plural, but it would be an unusual context in which there were distinctly different characters worthy of comment, and a deliberate contrast to the expected idiom.